# how to get only fileld values in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to get all the field values(not field names of a particular _id).
For example in `{"_id":"hello","a":"1","b":"2","c":"3"}`
By doing

```
var array = []

db.collection("example").find({
        "_id": "hello"
    })
    .forEach(function(doc) {
        Object.keys(doc).forEach(function(key) {
            array.push(key)
        })
    });
```

it's returning all filed names i.e `["a","b","c"]` but how to get only`["1","2","3"]`

Answer (score 1):

Object.keys gives you the field names. Try this:

```
db.collection("example").find({
        "_id": "hello"
    })
    .forEach(function(doc) {
        for (const key in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                array.push(obj[key])
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to print only values:

```
 db.collection.find({
        _id: 'hello'
    }, {
        _id: 0
    }).forEach(function(doc) {
        for (key in doc){
            print(doc[key])
        }
    })
```

Comment: While this might answer the question, just a couple words of explanation would go a long way.